# How to fix screen resolution after driver upgrade?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, login, resolution

For quite some time, I have had Ubuntu 15.04 installed and working well, using the nvidia-349 driver from the xorg-edgers ppa. However, I recently noticed that the nvidia-352 driver was available, so I uninstalled the 349 driver and switched over to the 352 driver. After a lot of problems, I switched back, as the 349 driver had been working quite well for me. However, now I am stuck with an obscure maximum screen resolution (864x486), which cannot be changed. The xorg.conf file I am using was generated by nvidia-xconfig from the command line.

No matter what I try, the problem persists. I've tried increasing the resolution through the nvidia-settings programs, but that doesn't do anything. Another (maybe) unrelated problem I've had is that the login screen is completely black (but still functional).

How can I get my screen resolution back?

Technical details:

-Lenovo Y50-70 touch

-1920x1080 touch screen

-Intel integrated + nVidia 860m gpu

-Kubuntu 15.04 w/upstart (systemd fails to boot)